# How to configure WordPress or Webhoster to always get the same URL?

Tags: wordpress, url

I made a webpage with wordpress: www.crossfitaorta.com . Everything works so far, but when I click on a link, the URL will change to my other domain I own (www.larsjakobeit.com/LINK). What and where do I have to change in order to always get: crossfitaorta.com as a domain and with a link: www.crossfitaorta.com/LINK. I am using the webhoster 1and1.com and I asked them about it, but they said the question is none of their business. But isnt changing the URL and Domainname a task for the webhoster?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it was very easy. I am sorry for this post, but maybe somebody struggles, too:).

In the box for Site address (URL): change the address to the new location, which should match the WordPress (your public site) address (URI).

Comment: That'll work for some things, but if you have URLs in your post contents, they won't be updated.  For example, [this page](http://www.crossfitaorta.com/beispiel-seite/) still contains a reference to http://larsjakobeit.com/aorta/wp-admin/.  Not that my answer would have covered this case, since the domain name is missing the www.  Always worth checking your site for incorrect links with something like [Xenu's Link Sleuth](http://home.snafu.de/tilman/xenulink.html)

Answer (score 1):

Chances are there's nothing wrong with the hosting, just some references to the old domain name in the database.  The easiest way to update the references is to use the "Search and Replace for WordPress Databases Script" mentioned in the [Moving WordPress Codex page](http://codex.wordpress.org/Moving_WordPress#When_Your_Domain_Name_or_URLs_Change).

Make sure you back your database up first, then replace all instances of www.larsjakobeit.com with www.crossfitaorta.com.

It's usually not safe to update the database directly, as some of the values will be PHP serialized, and changing values can break the serialization if the strings are different lengths.